# Why are there answers time stamped BEFORE the question?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, timestamps

**[Here is just one example.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1215557/how-can-i-get-class-based-objects-in-javascript-with-jquery/79507#79507)**

> answered Sep 17 '08 at 3:00

and

> asked Aug 1 '09 at 1:19

**[There's tons more](http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/10469/)**.

How does this happen?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because of merging questions.

See:
https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/improved-question-merging/

You can view the merges in the revision history for the question:
https://stackoverflow.com/posts/1215557/revisions

Comment: Thanks. I like the YT clip from Airplane.